# How to refresh CSS after button submit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I have two input fields in an ejs file that take hexcodes. When the hexcodes are entered and the submit button is clicked I set variables in my stylesheet to these hexcodes, and the background gradient is supposed to change. Is there a way I can refresh the stylesheet without doing a redirect or refreshing the whole page? Can just the background gradient be refreshed?

```
<script>
// fd is the form data
function setValue(fd) {
  let hexcode1 = fd.get('hexcode1');
  let hexcode2 = fd.get('hexcode2');

  r.style.setProperty('--color1', hexcode1);
  r.style.setProperty('--color2', hexcode2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: suppose you refreshed the style sheet according input value, the question is how you want to save entered value and display it later?

Comment: Did you check out this Mozilla Documentation? I think this does the same thing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookies for storing the hexcodes then take it from cookies even when page refreshes..

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cookieValue = getCookie('backgroundColor'),
      btns = document.querySelectorAll('.color-btn');

  if (cookieValue) {
    setBackgroundColor(cookieValue);
  }
  
  Array.from(btns).forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
      setBackgroundColor(color);
    });
  });
});

function setBackgroundColor(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  setCookie('backgroundColor', color);
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
      cookie = cookies.find(function(str) { return str.indexOf(name + '=') === 0; });
  if (cookie) {
    return cookie.split('=')[1];
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
}
```

CSS:

```css
body { background: red; }
button { padding: 1em; }
[data-color="red"] { background: red; }
[data-color="blue"] { background: blue; }
[data-color="green"] { background: green; }
```

HTML:

```html
<button class="color-btn" data-color="red"></button>
<button class="color-btn" data-color="blue"></button>
<button class="color-btn" data-color="green"></button>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sphj7v86/)

Note that the code used here for storing cookies gets deleted when the page closes..

So the user has to change it everytime..

You can prevent that by adding this code, (this keeps it for a year, change it to your wish) ↓

```js
var expiry = new Date();
expiry.setFullYear(expiry.getFullYear() + 1);
document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expiry.toUTCString() + ';';
```